# Azure DevOps Azure SQL Deployment - Incorrect Server Name

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-devops

I am getting the below error when I am trying to deploy the SQL script from the Azure DevOps. I can see the Server name is in correct format as well in the YAML file. Refer the screenshot, abc.database.windows.net The SQL server and database is also getting created from the ARM template deployment with the correct name in the Azure Resource group.

Error:

> Server name 'mySQLServer' is not in the correct format. Use a fully qualified domain name format like 'yyy.database.windows.net'

However, I am passing the correct FQDN of the server. Refer screenshot.

[image]

Any pointer on this issue?

Comment: The fact that the error is saying *"Server name 'mySQLServer"* strongly suggests that your statement *"I can see the Server name is in correct format"* is wrong.

Comment: I cannot reproduce above error with FQDN of the server provided. I could only get the error when I specify the `serverName: 'mySQLServer'` when I did the test.